# suppress page footer in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I want to display the address(6 lines) in first page only. i am applying suppress formula in page footer. The problem is the 6 line space are repeated in remaining pages.

thank u,

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around this limitation. Page headers and footers always take up a fixed amount of space. Without knowing any details about your report, the best suggestion I can make is to try putting your fields in a group footer or detail section that is set to print at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have an option called Suppress blank section in the Section Expert screen. If you select that then the section will be automatically suppressed if nothing is there, anyway you are conditionally suppressing it and I assume that you are suppressing it if the pagenumber is not equal to 1. So from page 2 the section will come as empty and enabling this flag will the suppress this space